# Is linear map the only one that is invariant under composition?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, neural-networks

The composition of linear maps is clearly linear. Suppose a funtion $f:A \mapsto B$ and it belongs to some certain function class $\mathcal{F}$: $f\in\mathcal{F}$. Does $f\circ f\in\mathcal{F}$ $\forall f\in\mathcal{F}$ imply that $\mathcal{F}$ is the collection of linear functionals (possibly up to the choice of $A$ and $B$ and continuity assumption)?

Comment: The set of (continuous, if you like) monotone increasing real functions is also closed under composition.

Comment: as is the set of constant functions

Answer (score 0):

No,  for example,  the set of rational functions  is invariant under composition.